# Restore Windows PowerShell to windowed mode

Tags: windows, windows-xp, powershell

How can I restore Windows PowerShell to windowed mode? I've set it to open in full screen; however, now I can't find a way to restore it to windowed mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Besides, you can always exit the shell with `exit` and modify the shortcut. Or go back to the GUI world with the Windows key, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and many other key combinations.